# What should be the result of boolean variable value for given regex match?

Tags: java, regex

```
String HouseNo = "a";
boolean value = HouseNo.matches("[0-9]+[/\\-]??[A-Za-z]");
```

According to me, the value should be true but it comes out to be false. Can anyone explain why?

Additionally I tried the regex

```
"[0-9]+[/\\-]??[A-Za-z[0-9]+]"
```

to match the input value "99-99" or "99-a" or "99-A" but not "99-" but it came out to be false. Can somebody explain this too?

Edits: I got the answer for 1st question. Actually in java ?? is equivalent to ? as given here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Still couldnt find answer to second question though. Can somebody help?

Comment: [0-9]+ is not conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-9]+` is not conditional

**EDIT**

According to your valid/invalid inputs the following regex might work for you

`([0-9]+[/\\-])?([A-Za-z]|[0-9]+)`

This basically conditionally evaluates a preceding Number plus a `-` or a `/` followed always by either a single Character  OR a Number

Comment: I got the answer for 1st question. Actually in java ?? is equivalent to ? as given here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: actually `??` is a reluctant quantifier while `?` is a greedy quantifier

Comment: any ideas about the second question which I asked?

Comment: @maverick28 Are these valid matches: `ABC`, `99-ABC`, `99/ABC`, `99-ABC99`?   Are these invalid matches: `99/`, `99-` ?

Comment: 99-ABC99, 99/, 99-, 99-ABC are invalid. ABC, 99-A, 99/C, 99-99 are valid input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56276/discussion-between-gtgaxiola-and-maverick28).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first Question:
+ in Regex means: "multiple times, but at least one time", meaning that you defenitely want a digit before the rest of the pattern.
If you want just letters to be possible as well, use * instead, which is: "zero or more times". 
Not sure if that makes sense though, if you are going for house numbers (probably can depent on different systems in different areas/countries).

The second one probably has similar problems...

Comment: I have edited my second question to give all inputs which I should accept. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Refering to your expected matches, you haven't been that far away. This should work (at least does in my text editor, tested with your examples):
[0-9]+[/\\-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+
Explanation:
- at least one digit
- followed by at least one special character
- followed by at least one digit or character.
If you string is longer then just the few characters, then maybe adding ? to the + is a good idea to make the + non greedy...

Answer (score 0):

"`[0-9]+`" is a problem for you.  The `+` metacharacter means "one or more," and you have zero numbers at the start of your string.

Comment: I got the answer for 1st question. Actually in java ?? is equivalent to ? as given here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html